# Why do I need "!" to use an array parameter while using a guard statement?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, guard-statement

Currently focused on structures and algorithms and I came across this one.

```
import Foundation

let numbers = [1, 3, 56, 66, 68, 80, 99, 105, 450]

func naiveContains(_ value: Int, in array: [Int]) -> Bool {
    guard !array.isEmpty else { return false }
    let midleIndex = array.count / 2
    
    if value <= array[midleIndex] {
        for index in 0...midleIndex {
            if array[index] == value {
                return true
            }
        }
    } else {
        for index in midleIndex..<array.count {
            if array[index] == value {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The exact location of my question is the guard statement:

```
guard !array.isEmpty else { return false }
```

I am not sure why the guard statement requires, ! in !array.isEmpty

I only need help in understanding why the exclamation mark needs to be placed before the array parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a negation operator so read it as "not". Personally I prefer to not use `guard` and the negation `!` in a case like this and instead write `if array.isEmpty { return }` since I find this much easier to read.

Comment: Definitely, easier to read that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm requires the array to be not empty. ! means not. So !array.isEmpty means is not empty.

The meaning of `guard ...` is like `if not ...`
So `guard !array.isEmpty` means `if not not array is empty`, which in turn is equivalent with `if array.isEmpty {return false}`

I can see it is confusing!

Comment: So, if it is not empty it will { return false}

Comment: No, if it is empty

Comment: I added explanation of `guard`. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I think you hit it on the nail with the new explanation. Thank you! @MarioHuizinga

Comment: @JeffLicona Guard means make sure it is something. After that there is an else to be executed if that condition is not met.